# Gnuplot in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, gnuplottex

I am trying to get a plot using gnuplottex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, latexsym, keyval, ifthen, moreverb}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=rotate]
    plot sin(x)
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{My figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get caption without any figure. I am using TeXShop. How can I get the plot.

Comment: Did you look in the log file? I get a warning like this: ``
Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself``

Comment: Plus: `Package gnuplottex Warning: Gnuplot execution produced errors: set terminal epslatex rotate`

Comment: @daleif The log file has a line: Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert gnuplt-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually. So, what is to be done here.

Comment: you tell me. gnuplot is an external programme, it is not a part of latex. Do you have it installed? if so, run gnuplot on that file.

Comment: Note that unless you really need to, there is mot much reason to use gnuplot to for example plot a function. LaTeX can do that by itself using pgfplots.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the warning with `terminaloptions = rotate`. The following code works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, latexsym, keyval, ifthen, moreverb}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
    plot sin(x)
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption{My figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As daleif already noted in the comments, I would recommend you not to use `gnuplottex`, since there are way better alternatives as `pgfplots`.